# Multpeer Connectivity - Checking if all nearby peers are connected and trying to reconnect them

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

I have couple of questions regarding Multipeer Connectivity framework. I have multiple devices(browsers) connecting to one device(advertiser) automatically. Now, the problem is usually most of the peers connect but one or two don't connect (session state comes back as "Not Connected"). I try to automatically reconnect them by deleting the session/browser/advertiser and reallocating them. But again most of the times they just don't connect. I would like to know if anyone knows the reason behind this. If  am missing something or doing anything wrong. Or what can I do in this scenario?

Secondly, how can I check if all the peers nearby are connected to means I can try to send some data to them. I mean I have connectedPeers array from session but it does not tell me how many peers are still trying to connect, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend changing your design so that there is only one browser, and all the other peers are advertisers. The browsing process really degrades network performance, and if you have multiple browsers, you'll experience more connection issues and slower transfers.

What's more, if you have only one browser, that browser should be able to tell when all the peers have connected or not, since it should be aware of all the peers.

Also, not sure if you're doing this or not, but if it works for your project, you can create a separate `MCSession` object for each [master/browser, client/advertiser] pair. That way, if you fail to connect to one peer, you can tear down the `MCSession` just for that peer, and keep the other peers connected in their separate sessions.

Comment: Thanks -- cutting down on browsers really helped with my connection problems.   This appears to be a good workaround for the moment.